# Limits and functions

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, proof-explanation

If $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a,$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then how do I prove that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(f(x))=g(a),$$ where $f, g$ are well-defined functions?

Comment: I was editing, now the question is complete.

Comment: For this to be true $g(x)$ has to be continuous around $a$

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong! Take $g(x)=0$ for $x\neq a$ and $g(a)=1$.

It's true if $g$ is a continuous function in $x=a$.